# Is there any way to use root project class from sub projects in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am using gradle 4.4.1 and my project structure like the following..

```html
/javaprojects
|- build.gradle
|- (Java Sources and files) //src/main/java/com/myfile/Hello.java
|- /api
     |- (Java Sources and files)
```

I want to use the Hello.java in the **api** project. How to use Hello.java from the root directory into api directory?

My build.gradle,

```
allprojects {

  apply plugin: 'application'
  apply plugin: 'java'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
  }

 project(':api') {
  dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
  }
}

mainClassName = 'com.myfile.HelloWorld'
```

How the gradle will support to use this case?

Kindly provide your thoughts.

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having right now? Is it not building? Is your Hello.class not being compiled? Are you asking for advice?

Comment: no. The api diectory doesn't know the Hello.class when I compile.. getting  error: cannot find symbol

Comment: Post the contents of your `build.gradle`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Sam! I have updated my post. Kindly review and provide your thoughts.

Comment: The root project must be added to the compile dependencies of the api project.https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:declaring_project_dependency, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_and_task_paths

Comment: @JBNizet here How can I add compile dependencies? compile project(':javaprojects') is this ok?

Comment: No. But you should test before asking. As said in the second link I posted in my previous comment: "A project path has the following pattern: It starts with an optional colon, which denotes the root project. The root project is the only project in a path that is not specified by its name.". So you need to add `compile project(':')` in the api project dependencies. The `project(':api') { ... }` should be out of the allprojects closure (or better, its body should be in the api project's build.gradle file)

Comment: Ya, actually I tried this.  Thank you! :)